# Keyboard shortcut to change color scheme in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

is there a way to assign a keyboard shortcut to a specific color scheme in Sublime Text 2? In Emacs it's easy to define a function that toggles "night-mode" color scheme and assigns it to a keyboard shortcut, I was wondering if you can also do it in ST2.

Piotr

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try something like this, in your user key binding:

```
{
    "keys": ["YOUR_SHORTCUT"],
    "command": "set_setting",
    "args":
    {
        "setting": "color_scheme",
        "value": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Solarized (Light).tmTheme"
    }
}
```

Of course, change `Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Solarized (Light).tmTheme` to whatever theme you prefer.

If you want a toggle between two color schemes, you can create a plugin (`Tools/New Plugin...`):

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ToggleColorSchemeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, **args):

        scheme1 = args["color_scheme_1"]
        scheme2 = args["color_scheme_2"]
        current_scheme = self.view.settings().get("color_scheme")

        new_scheme = scheme1 if current_scheme == scheme2 else scheme2
        self.view.settings().set("color_scheme", new_scheme)
```

and save it in your `Packages/User` directory.

Then add a key binding like this:

```
{  
    "keys": ["YOUR_TOGGLE_SHORCUT"], "command": "toggle_color_scheme",
    "args":
    {
        "color_scheme_1": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Solarized (Light).tmTheme" ,
        "color_scheme_2": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Solarized (Dark).tmTheme"
    }
}
```

Comment: @Riccardo Is there also a way to toggle between three schemes?

Comment: Awesome, +1!
Any way to do this with themes (for example, toggling Soda Dark/Light along with the color scheme)? I tried getting and setting `"theme"` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Riccardo, nifty plugin. Do you know why this only changes the current tab's view setting instead of the global one (other tabs remain in the color scheme defined in User settings). I guess I should become more familiar with the Sublime API.

Comment: In the [settings documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/settings.html), it specifies, for `set_setting`, that
"*The settings modified here are buffer specific settings: they override any settings placed in a settings file, but apply to the current file only.*"

At the moment, I'm not aware of a way to change global settings, sorry...

Comment: Awesome tipp, thanks! As an addition: I set `F3` to toggle between 2 light themes and `F4` to toggle two dark themes, so I can actually switch between 4 themes using this code

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to bother with editing config files you can install [SchemeCycle](https://github.com/rrerolle/sublime-scheme-cycler).

Then cycle color schemes with <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+F8</kbd>. With 2 themes (Dark / Light) it acts as toggling.

---

If you prefer Command Palette check [Norris's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14932030/1136008) answer or try [ColorSchemeSelector](https://github.com/jugyo/SublimeColorSchemeSelector) with `: Select Color Scheme` command, it will not pollute your pallete as much as [Schemr](https://github.com/skt84/Schemr).

Visualization AKA screens:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! The real answer.

Answer (score 10):

To change global color scheme settings (not just the current view), alter Riccardo's answer like this:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ToggleColorSchemeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, **args):
        s = sublime.load_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")

        scheme1 = args["color_scheme_1"]
        scheme2 = args["color_scheme_2"]
        current_scheme = s.get("color_scheme", scheme1)

        new_scheme = scheme1
        if current_scheme == scheme1:
          new_scheme = scheme2

        if current_scheme == scheme2:
         new_scheme = scheme1

        s.set("color_scheme", new_scheme)

        sublime.save_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")
```

Make sure all of your views are set to one color scheme before using this!

This should work no matter what your color schemes are currently set to under "Preferences.sublime-settings - User" and "Preferences.sublime-settings - Default".

I gleaned this information from Schemrs code: https://github.com/benweier/Schemr/blob/master/schemr.py
and the font-changing code: "Packages\Default\font.py"

Comment: +1 I used this code to change both my theme and color scheme with one keybind.

Comment: This is great, how would I change this to apply not to the global user preferences, but to the syntax specific preferences, for example `/User/Markdown.sublime-settings`

Answer (score 7):

I just found this nice little plugin:
https://github.com/skt84/Schemr

Which doesn't exactly allow you to bind, but gives you a Command Palette access instead, which does just perfect for me. *(Just in case anyone stumbled on this via google like myself.)*

Answer (score 5):

To support multiple color schemes one would alter Riccardos answer like so:

```
class ToggleColorSchemeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, **args):

        scheme1 = args["color_scheme_1"]
        scheme2 = args["color_scheme_2"]
        scheme3 = args["color_scheme_3"]
        current_scheme = self.view.settings().get("color_scheme")

        new_scheme = scheme1
        if current_scheme == scheme1:
          new_scheme = scheme2

        if current_scheme == scheme2:
         new_scheme = scheme3

        self.view.settings().set("color_scheme", new_scheme)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to change a color scheme along with a theme with [Camaleon plugin](https://github.com/titoBouzout/Camaleon).

Comment: Actually it does. Just tried it, funny plugin. However you can switch one way only it seems and you don't know which one you are switching to.

Answer (score 3):

If someone interested I just created a plugin to toggle between N different theme and colorscheme configurations. Check it out here:

https://gist.github.com/andresbravog/9429793